# Pattern Searching in Pig Script

Tags: pattern-matching, apache-pig

This code isn't giving any output:

```
log= LOAD '/user/mady/hadoop_project' AS (month,date,time,info1,info2,info3);
grp= FILTER log BY ($5 MATCHES '.*failed');
STORE grp INTO 'sample8';
```

I'm trying to search for the word 'failed' in the input file ($5 column) but using `MATCHES` keyword isn't working..

Comment: Please show a sample of input data that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is wrong.  Use `'.*failed.*'`.  As it is you will only match strings ending in "failed".